# How to update a value from all mongo documents from string to array?

Tags: mongodb

My mongo documents look like this

```
   {
      "_id": "5e816eab7ed25c3d99c10749",
      "category": [
        "bookmarks",
        "too read"
      ],
      ....
   },
```

I would like to update the category array to be an Object array, like so:

```
"category": [
        {
            "pin": false,
            "value": "bookmarks"
        },
        {
            "pin": false,
            "value": "to read"
        }
      ],
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of category array

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      category: {
        $map: {
          input: "$category",
          in: {
            pin: false,
            value: "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kdBY9NnRa8Z)

---

For the lower version you can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to clone result and updated documents in another blank collection,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      category: {
        $map: {
          input: "$category",
          in: {
            pin: false,
            value: "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "give your collection name" }
])
```